# Is EntityFramework intelligent enough to fire one query instead of two in this situation?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have an existing controller action as below.

```
Public Function List(ByVal UserID As Integer, Optional ByVa; Filter As String = Nothing) As ActionResult
    Dim records

    If Filter IsNot Nothing Then
        records = context.Contacts.Where(Function(x) x.UserID = UserID and x.Name.Contains(Filter))
    Else
        records = context.Contacts.Where(Function(x) x.UserID = UserID)
    End If

    return View(records)
End Function
```

I desire to make it simpler as below.

```
Public Function List(ByVal UserID As Integer, Optional ByVa; Filter As String = Nothing) As ActionResult
    Dim records = context.Contacts.Where(Function(x) x.UserID = UserID)

    If Filter IsNot Nothing Then
        records = records.Where(Function(x) x.Name.Contains(Filter))
    End If

    return View(records)
End Function
```

Will EF fire two queries if Filter is passed or is it intelligent enough to fire just one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, one query - this is the nature of the IQueryable interface. All methods which return an IQueryable **should** not execute anything until the IQueryable's enumerator is accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Try it and see!

Fire up SQL Management Studio (or similar) and load up SQL Profiler, connect to the DB and see what incoming queries are there.

In theory there is no reason why EF4 shouldn't be able to run it as a single op since the request for data doesn't come until after the where clause is applied for the second time.

- Build query
- Add where clause
- Add second where clause
- Execute data retrieval